# conda version in terminal finds wheel instead of exe

Tags: python, anaconda

when I launch this on terminal `conda version` I get

```
wheel 0.30.0
```

even if I added conda command to system variables pointing at the .exe.

Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: anaconda/bin missing 0.0